# Track shareDialog in Twitter in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, twitter

I am trying to integrate twitter's share functionality to my project. I am able to create the dialog for the same and sharing functionality is also working fine. But after the share dialog box is opened, I am not able to determine wether the user is actually tweeting or just closing the window.

Is there a way to determine wether the user tweeted or just closed the dialog window?

I tried by using twitter javascript sdk but it didnt worked also many npm module which also failed to solve my problem.

Following is the code that I am using to generate the share dialog for twitter

`HTML`

```
<div  id="twitter-share" className="icon-fill-2">
    <a class="twitter-share-button" href="http://google.com">
        Tweet
    </a>
</div>
```

[Upon clicking the hyperlink following page opens up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzJy0.png)

Comment: Please include the code you used trying to solve the problem in your question.

Comment: @gst There was not much code written but I have included the html tag that I was using to generate the share dialog for twitter.
Please tell me if this is helpful.

Comment: I am looking for something of a callback here that would help me determine if the user has actually tweeted or not after clicking on the share button.